# Use Windbg find argumet passed to a COM+ method

Tags: com, windbg, com+

Generated a debug diagnostic dump file for a COM+ application. Upon analysis look like threads deadlocks at line `OLE32!SwitchSTA`. My symbol path is pointing to msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols. Is there way to know what arguments were passed to this method?

In general, how does one use Windbg to find the input argument value to the method call?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call

```
kP
```

and it will dump the call stacks with the parameters